# Laravel Eloquent model JSON output format

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

my problem is about the JSON format I recieve when sending a query to the database.
The output I want:

```
[{"errors":[{"something":"something"}],"created_at":"2020-10-20 10:10:10","name":"something","id":99}]
```

I get :

```
[{"id":99,"name":"something","device_results":[{"devices_id":99,"created_at":"2020-10-20 10:10:10","errors":[{"something":"something"}]}]}]
```

Which I get with:

```
public function errors()
    {
        $errors = DB::table('devices')
            ->join('device_results', 'devices.id', '=', 'device_results.devices_id')
            ->select('errors', 'created_at', 'name', 'device_results.id')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->whereJsonLength('errors', '>', 0)
            ->get();

        return $errors;
    }
```

I would like to get the same results with using my model because if I do this:

```
public function errors()
    {
        $devices = Devices::with(['device_results' => function($query) {
            $query->select('device_results.devices_id','created_at','errors')
            ->whereJsonLength('errors', '>', 0)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
        }])->get();

        return $devices;
    }
```

Is it always in this format or can I use the model and get the same format as with the DB class? I am using Vue for the front end and would like to avoid nesting.

Thank you

Comment: If you use models with relations, the result will be always nested. Every relation will be loaded as a separate object or collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to create a `Resource` ?
The doc : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: Why does this "answer" only contain a question and a hyperlink?